# how to add subtitle from a URL file in vitamio player?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, vitamio

I am trying to fetch my subtitle(.srt) file from url and set it into addTimedTextSource() method.But the issue is addTimedTextSource() takes only subtile path as parameter not url.
I am using vitamio Player with my app

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    if (!LibsChecker.checkVitamioLibs(this))
      return;
    setContentView(R.layout.videobuffer);
    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.buffer);
    pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.probar);
    testview=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);

    downloadRateView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.download_rate);
    loadRateView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.load_rate);
        mVideoView.addTimedTextSource(subtitle_path);//I want to use URL for this part.
    mVideoView.setTimedTextShown(true);


    mVideoView.setOnTimedTextListener(new OnTimedTextListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTimedTextUpdate(byte[] pixels, int width, int height) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTimedText(String text) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            testview.setText(text);
            Log.d("test","test");

        }
    });
    if (path == "") {
      // Tell the user to provide a media file URL/path.
      Toast.makeText(
          VideoViewBuffer.this,
          "Please edit VideoBuffer Activity, and set path"
              + " variable to your media file URL/path", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      return;
    } else {

      uri = Uri.parse(path);
      mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
      mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
      mVideoView.requestFocus();
      mVideoView.setOnInfoListener(this);
      mVideoView.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
      mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
          // optional need Vitamio 4.0
          mediaPlayer.setPlaybackSpeed(1.0f);
        }
      });
    }

  }
```

Is their any other way to add url and pass it in addtimedTextSource(subtitlefile).

Comment: Same problem, after 1 yeah, none documentation.